# Offset In Mouse Look Script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My object is supposed to be looking at the mouse, instead it looks behind.

My Code:

```
var dir = Input.mousePosition - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

It looks like:
[image]

(I had to draw the mouse because the photo tool i use doesn't put in the mouse)

Is there a way to make it look directly at it, instead of whenever i move the mouse be behind it? And if you use a different method could you please explain why my method doesn’t work, and also state why yours does? By preference I’d like to keep my same method, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding 90 degrees or 45 to fix the rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html), all you need to do is pass it the position you want the object to face.

Your code would look something like this:

```
public void Update {
     Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
     transform.LookAt(mousePos);
}
```

If you only want the object to turn and not look up\down then keep where your object is looking  on the same y value.

Comment: And how can I do that? (Locking the rotation on x and y axis)

Comment: Well one way is to move the position that you are looking at to the same level as you so instead of looking down or up you are looking straight at it. 

mousePos.y = transform.position.y